# What type of ANN architecture to choose?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, architecture, model-request

I have $N$ number of teachers  each of which has an input feature vector ($25$ dimensional) consisting of positive numerical values for different quality of aspects (for example: lecturing ability, knowledge capacity, communication skills, etc.). I want to design an ANN to output a single quality index based on these quality features.

What type of ANN architecture is appropriate for this problem?

Comment: AFAIK this is still a research topic. Are you starting a PhD on it?

Comment: no,  but still for some specific  problems it is well-known that some architectures work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have structured/tabular data. So, a fully-connected feedforward network should do the job.

Comment: What does structured/tabular data mean? are all data not structured/tabular?

Comment: @user3489173 Nope. Text data isn't tabular for example.